# Fallo al inicializar array bidimensional NullPointerException Java

Tags: java, array, nullpointerexception, array-bidimensional

Al tratar de inicializar un array bidimensional me sale el error del título: `java.lang.NullPointerException`. He probado con varias las soluciones a otras preguntas pero no me han funcionado. Tengo un método que inicializa la variable:

```
Tesela [][] teselas;
```

No puedo inicializarla antes porque no sé las dimensiones hasta que me las diga un fichero. De este modo obtengo `nFilas` y `nColumnas` que paso al método `inicializar`:

```
public void inicializar(int nFilas, int nColumnas){
      for(int i=0; i<nFilas; i++){
            for(int j=0; j<nColumnas; j++){
                  tesela[i][j] = new Tesela(Color.BLANCO());
            }
      }
}
```

Donde Tesela es una clase a la que basta con pasarle el color, de este modo crearía una matriz nFilas x nColumnas de color blanco.
No empleo la variable teselas hasta después de llamar a `inicializar(nFilas, nColumnas);`

Comment: No puedes usar el arreglo sin inicializarlo

Comment: Podrías declararlo dentro del método, de ese modo ya puedes agregar las dimensiones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En Java los arreglos son objetos, por lo que almacenan realmente una referencia que apunta a los datos. Si no se han inicializado con un valor, se genera una excepción `NullPointerException`. Como se describe en esta [pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/42977/cu%C3%A1l-es-la-soluci%C3%B3n-a-todos-los-errores-nullpointerexception-presentes-pasados)

Para solucionarlo, debes inicializar el arreglo antes de usarlo.

```
teselas = new Tesela[nFilas][nColumnas];
```